# sql where Query error as Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql

While writing Stored procedure why I'm getting this error

```
Create Proc sp_generateToken
As
declare @typeofcust varchar(10)
declare @maxnumber int
Begin
set @typeofcust = (select * from Client where Client_Id = 1);
set @maxnumber= (select coalesce (MAX(cust_RegiId),0) from Customer_registeraion)
End
```

Please help me why im getting this error

Comment: Im guessing it's because you're SELECTing everything from the `Client` table and trying to put it into a `varchar`....which you cannot do. You could create a temp table and do an `INSERT` `SELECT`

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Change `select * from` to `select typeofcust from`.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is this line here:

```
set @typeofcust = (select * from Client where Client_Id = 1);
```

Like my comment says you're trying to return everything from that table where `Client_Id = 1` and trying to put it into a `varchar`...

I think, (if you are simply trying to get the typeofcust), you should return the `TOP(1) typeOfCust` or whatever the column is from the Client table.

However, if you are wanting to actually return everything, you'd have to create a temp table and do a select into such as:

```
INSERT INTO #temp
(
   // columns
)
SELECT 
(
    // Columns
)
FROM Client
   WHERE Client_Id = 1
```